# Kubernetes CPU allocation: is vCore vs vCPU vs core in Azure?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, hyperthreading, vcpu

I am running a Java application on an Azure Kubernetes node with a Standard_D8s_v3 VM. I am unsure about CPU allocation for a kubernetes deployment. [This](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/#cpu-units) mentions that 1 CPU is equals to 1 Azure vCore. However the Azure VM specs mentions that Standard_D8s_v3 has 8 vCPUs (not vCores). What is the difference between vCPU and vCore?

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/acu) you can see that the ratio of a Ds_v3 VM vCPU to cores (not vCores) is 2:1 due to Hyperthreading. Which means that 2 vCPUs are needed for the same performance of 1. Is vCore == core? If so, my assumption is that I should double the size of the VM.

Or, should I assume that 1 kubernetes CPU is equals to 1 vCPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, 1 Kubernetes CPU equals 1 vCPU.

For example i am using `Standard_D4s_v3` nodes which have 4 vCPU according to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/virtual-machines/dv3-dsv3-series#dsv3-series).

When i do

```
kubectl get nodes
kubectl describe node <node-name>
```

i can see this

```
Capacity:
  cpu:                            4
Allocatable:
  cpu:                            3860m
```

Here is also good explanation whats the difference between a Core and vCPU on [Azure](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5a2a0e1b-8439-4c43-ae7f-11c50ad94cb0/difference-between-azure-vm-core-and-vcpu?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows).

Comment: Thanks for the good answer! This is not very clear in the K8s documentation. I guess they have not updated the page since they changed the CPU concept of azure.

Comment: perfect. Can you please mark the answer pls as correct to help other users with the same questions ?

Answer (score 0):

The CPU resource is measured in CPU units. One CPU, in Kubernetes, is equivalent to:

```
1 AWS vCPU
1 GCP Core
1 Azure vCore
1 Hyperthread on a bare-metal Intel processor with Hyperthreading
```